# Open a file in a function and write to it

Tags: python

I created the function below:

```
def print_form(x):
    f = open('/home/rv/Plone/Zope-2.10.11-final-py2.4/Extensions/test.fasta', 'w')
    f.write(str(x))
    f.close()
    return x
```

The function returns and prints, but doesnt write it to a file or creates it?

---

**EDIT**

I editied the above code the so the file is created in a specific location but it still isnt there

Comment: Are you sure you're looking in the right place for the file? How are you invoking the script?

Comment: A variable is parsed to the function. e.g. name = 'david',

print print_form(name)

Comment: @Amber is most likely right, the file is being created but not where you are expecting to find it.

Comment: Checked my current directory and the directory provided by os.path both were exactly the same location as the script, but there is no "form.fasta" file

Comment: Try writing the file to /home/rv, or /tmp.  Somewhere you *know* you have write access, i.e. if `touch /tmp/test.fasta` creates the file where it was not there before.

Comment: Also, check if this code is inside a `try: ... except: pass` block or something similar which may be discarding an exception.

Answer (score 1):

The file 'form.fasta' will be created in the current working directory.  This is usually whatever directory you're in when you invoke the script.

To see what your current directory is, add:

```
print(os.path.abspath(os.curdir))
```

or equivalent.

Also, make sure `f.write(x)` converts `x` to something fit to be written; you might want `f.write(str(x))` or `f.write(repr(x))` or even `f.write(unicode(x))`.

Finally, just because you called `f.close()` doesn't necessarily mean the OS has immediately flushed it out to the disk.  (I can't seem to find a Python equivalent to C's `setvbuf()` function, which would let you switch a file stream to unbuffered mode.)

P.S. One more thing: If `x` is, say, an integer, just writing it to a file doesn't end the file with a line end character.  If you have a one-line file without a line end, and you print it out, and you're like me and have a bash prompt string that starts with the line-clear control code, it will look exactly like the output you get from an empty file.